# how to match only part of the expression to string in ocamllex

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I have a simple ocamllex program where the rules section looks somewhat like this-

```
let digits= ['0'-'9']
let variables= 'X'|'Z'

rule addinlist = parse
|['\n']  {addinlist lexbuf;}
| "Inc" '(' variables+ '(' digits+ ')' ')' as ine { !inputstringarray.(!inputstringarrayi) <-ine;
                                        inputstringarrayi := !inputstringarrayi +1;
                                        addinlist lexbuf}
|_ as c
{ printf "Unrecognized character: %c\n" c;
addinlist lexbuf
}
| eof { () }
```

My question is suppose I want to match Inc(X(7)) such that I can convert it to my abstract syntax which is "Inc of var of int". I want my lexer to give me the separate strings while reading Inc(X(7)) such that I get "Inc" as a diff string (say inb) followed by "X" as a diff string (say inc) n followed by "7" as a diff string (say ind), so that i can play around with these strings inb, inc, & ind, instead of being stuck with a whole string ine, as is given by my program. How to go about this? I hope my question is clear

Comment: It's hard to answer because it's not clear what your problem actually is. Are you trying to learn ocamllex? Are you trying to build a quick and dirty tool? Are you trying to learn how to process languages in general? What you want is completely standard, you just need to write a "real" lexical analyzer. Or you could consider just using the Genlex module, a generic lexical analyzer. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's ok. I just had to edit the sentence into  "Inc" '(' (variables+ as abc) '(' (digits+ as def) ')' ')' to get the strings separately